# Cannot find any of custom classes in my project

Tags: java, package, structure

I've just save my project and everything was OK, I pushed local repo to remote one and then I got errors while compiling: "Cannot find symbol: class MyClass"

[image: img].

I found that it depends on location

[image: img2]

and package declaration but I can't find the solution. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Can share the headers of the file , the imports ? You don't have to just have the clas in other file, you have to import them

Comment: It's also variables that can't be found. Check if you've declared all those variables.

Comment: Is it because of a space in your project path "PJAIK dev" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved, I decided to delete folder 'SpaceInvadersGame' in 'src' and 'out' and move its content directly behind it. Then Intelisense said to move it back to package. Probably some meta-data has been actualized and everything now works fine.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuVL2.jpg)